# Referencing a file in a parent directory

Tags: php

Is this the right way to go about referencing a file in a parent directory relative to a php source file?:

```
require_once('../referenced_file.php');
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't seem to have any effect" mean? require should kill your script if it doesn't find the file. Can you paste the error?

Comment: Yaw, you should post an error message, or, if you don't have one, you have to get it somehow. Try to look into error_log

Comment: I'll check out the error log, thanks

Comment: The error message will give you full path to the file, so, you can have an idea of the actual file locations. And the reason, of course. In general, such a code should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To include a file relative to the current source file you should use the full path:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../referenced_file.php';
```

As the current working directory is set to the directory of the script that was initially executed.

Comment: You don't know the working directory for sure. it can be sub-include and will lead to wrong path as well. Everyone is up with code to get precious rep, but noone bother to think before post. I really love SO, A lamer's heaven.

Comment: @Col. This code works fine irrespective of the current working directory. It includes a file in the parent directory relative to the source file (the file that line of code is in).

Comment: @Col. From the question post: Is this the right way to go about referencing a file in a parent directory **relative to a php source file?**. Irrespective of what the error is the method in the question isn't the correct method.

Comment: @Col. Given that recently on average my answers are 4 days apart and in that time I gave about as many downvotes as upvotes do you think I really give a damn about how high my reputation is? Please don't insult me :)

Comment: Ok, I may be wrong this time. I see many automated answers and it makes me sick.